# Julia - How to launch an Executable file from REPL

Tags: julia, executable

I am trying to open a program through Julias REPL. I would like the result to be as if I had double-clicked on the .exe file in the file explorer.

I have tried using `` run(`program.exe`) `` but it could not find the file. Then I realized that I needed a command in front so I tried `` run(`run program.exe`) ``. This seems to find the program but it crashes immediately.

Comment: Have you tried `run(full_path_to_the_executable/program.exe)`?

Comment: Yes I did try that. It gave the same error message as before ( IOError: could not spawn `xfoil.exe`: unknown error (UNKNOWN) ) where xfoil.exe is the program.

Comment: The answer given by hckr (with `cmd /c`) would be my second step. Does it work for you (as I see you have not accepted it)?

Comment: Sorry, I replied to you before looking into hckr's answer and have since accepted it. There were unusual circumstances which made your response give an error that have sense been addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your computer's operating system is a Windows.

You might need to use full path to your executable file and the nice way to enter a path while creating a command object with ``` `` ``` is creating a string and *interpolate* it. Otherwise spaces and special characters may create a problem. Here is an example,

```
path = "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
run(`$path`)
```

However, running this way is not always like double-clicking an EXE file. The running executable might still be attached to your terminal and you may not run new commands in Julia REPL until the created process exits. For example, try the following and try entering a command in Julia REPL without closing the window:

```
run(`notepad`)
```

If you do not want this behavior, you can use `run` with `wait=false` keyword option.

```
run(`$path`, wait=false)
```

If wait is false, the process runs asynchronously and the process' I/O streams are directed to `devnull`. This actually does not detach process. If you kill `julia` process, the executable's process will also be killed.

You can instead use `cmd /c start` to open the executable in another `cmd` window. The executable's process should be detached from Julia.

```
run(`cmd /c start $path`)
```

You might find more information regarding running external programs in [the relevant entry](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/) of the Julia manual.

Comment: Thank you for this. It works now. Turns out the executable got corrupted somehow and was returning an unknown error to julia when it tried to run. The cmd start command understood this and was able to give a meaningful error. The application now opens in the REPL which is desired. Do you have any insight on how to move this concept into the ``open(`program.exe`,"r+")`` area? The program still crashes upon startup when launched this way.

Comment: @hckr, you do not need to use `cmd /c start` - the run `run` command has an option for that - e.g. `run(\`notepad\`, wait=false)`

Comment: @Przemyslaw Szufel: sometimes you need `cmd /c`, e.g. you have to use it to run `dir` under Windows.

Comment: the comment was about `cmd /c start` not `cmd /c` itself. `start` detaches the process and `wait=false` can be used instead.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel I have added `wait=false` to the answer, though `wait=false` does not detach the process: if you kill `julia` process, the executable's process also dies.

Comment: @user3013702 I do not think so. `cmd /c start` creates an independent process, `open` AFAIK needs a subprocess. I am not an expert but maybe redirecting `stderr` to a file or somewhere else to see the error might help. You can use `pipeline` to redirect I/O. Also, might it be that the author of the exe made it so that the process can't run as a subprocess? People may take some measures to try to prevent reverse-engineering, for example...

Comment: The process can be piped. I am currently doing it in C++ with popen(). Accrording to my research, ``open(`program.exe`,"r+")`` is supposed to allow interaction with the program.I'll investigate using `pipeline()`

Comment: @hckr I got it working. To read/write to the program I had to use: ``p = open(pipeline(`program.exe`),"r+")`` and then `write(p,"foo"). Thanks for all of your help!